# imputing missing dates for multiple columns in a dataframe based on businessdate index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have a dataframe of the below nature

```
A_DATE       A_VALUE      B_DATE       B_VALUE     C_DATE      C_VALUE
2014-04-04   2.1          2014-04-04   4.8         2014-04-04   0.6
2014-04-05   2.3          2014-04-08   4.9         2014-04-05   0.8
2014-04-09   2.2          2014-04-09   4.6         2014-04-08   0.2
```

And I have a datetime series generated via

```
 pd.bdate_range('2013-03-27', '2018-03-28')
```

How Can i have a dataframe that will look like below:

```
INDEX         A_DATE       A_VALUE      B_DATE       B_VALUE     C_DATE      C_VALUE
2014-04-04   2014-04-04   2.1          2014-04-04   4.8         2014-04-04   0.6
2014-04-05   2014-04-05   2.3          NA            NA         2014-04-05   0.8
2014-04-08   NA            NA          2014-04-08   4.9         2014-04-08   0.2
2014-04-09   2014-04-09   2.2          2014-04-09   4.6         NA            NA
```

Am aware of functions such as `pd.merge_asof` and `pd.merge_ordered`, however I assume i will have to first split the dataframe into multiple subsets before applying the merge back to combine all dataframes as per the index generated from `pd.bdate`_range ?
Any other ways will be very helpful

Thanks as always

Comment: It's always nice if you provide some code to reproduce your data.

Comment: Do you need multiple datetimes columns?

Comment: No, just the index can be datetime..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest convert all columns to `DatatimeIndex` instead multiple `datetime` columns:

```
idx = pd.bdate_range('2014-04-01', '2014-04-10')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = (df.stack(0)
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .set_index('DATE', append=True)['VALUE']
       .unstack(level=0)
       .reindex(idx))
print (df)
              A    B    C
2014-04-01  NaN  NaN  NaN
2014-04-02  NaN  NaN  NaN
2014-04-03  NaN  NaN  NaN
2014-04-04  2.1  4.8  0.6
2014-04-07  NaN  NaN  NaN
2014-04-08  NaN  4.9  0.2
2014-04-09  2.2  4.6  NaN
2014-04-10  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) columns to `MultiIndex`
2. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by first level
3. Remove first level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
4. Append `DATE` to `MultiIndex`
5. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
6. Last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: @asimo - Super, give me some time for explanation.